# Amazon AWS EC2 + Puppet, get Puppet to know AWS instance tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, puppet

I am having a problem with my AWS deployment, fairly new to AWS and Puppet.

So coming to my question - can you distinguish puppet nodes with AWS machine tags or CNAME domains?

A little background about the plan:

- have multiple clusters of machines, one php cluster, one legacy php cluster, one java cluster, one perl cluster
- control configuration with puppet - still pretty new to puppet but as a developer I like the idea of being able to version control configuration of servers
- have autoscaling enabled on those clusters - obviously the main benefit of the cloud that makes the much hight cost when it comes to any reasonable performance worth it (those amazon machines are slower than my phone...)
- deployment controlled by Capistrano, this makes things a lot easier

So in AWS you get those super nasty public/private machine dns's... no way you can identify machines on those. In order to easer the problem, seams like AWS want's you to tag everything - so I did. Found a script that makes a CNAME record for each machine with the tag "ShortName" thanks to the Route53 API.

Every machine has a ShortName tag that becomes its CNAME, unfortunately puppet still resolves the private dns name.

I'd like to have

```
node 'perl-cluster'{}
```

in puppet, anyone any clue ho to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

The way I've done it is to write a custom fact for the server to identify its role from user data, which can be accessed on 169.254.169.254, see your own **user data**...

[AWS user-data documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AESDG-chapter-instancedata.html)

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/
```

so when I type `facter role` ill get 'dbserver', 'webserver' whatever, then use that to define a node, its important not to have autoscaling groups care the slightest about what the name of the server is.

/etc/puppet/manifests/nodes.pp

```
node default{
  include nodes::type
}
```

/etc/puppet/modules/nodes/manifests/init.pp

```
import “type.pp”
```

/etc/puppet/modules/nodes/manifests/type.pp

```
class nodes::type{
   case $role {
     “dbserver” : {
       include mysql
     }
   }
   case $role {
      “webserver” : {
       include httpd
     }
   }
}
```

/etc/puppet/manifests/modules.pp

```
 import nodes
```

I dont want to tell you exactly how to do it in your case, but here I'll show you how to create a custom fact to report the EC2 instance ID.

Facter, curl, are installed.

```
mkdir -p /home/ec2-user/lib/ruby/facter
export FACTERLIB=/home/ec2-user/lib/ruby/facter

cat > /home/ec2-user/lib/ruby/facter/instance_id < EOF
# instance_id.rb
#
require 'facter'
Facter.add("instance_id") do
    setcode "/usr/bin/curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id"
    end
EOF
```

And lo, a custom fact was written.

Now I can use it to get the ec2 instance id:

```
$ facter instance_id
i-a1c0ffee
```

I dont have puppet installed on this machine, but if i wanted it available to puppet, id put in it /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter, and to distribute it to clients id ensure pluginsync=true in puppet.conf.

Bear in mind, all that ive said is highly subjective, its just how I do it, if theres a better way, I'd be interested.

Comment: Ok, so do I need to have ec2 tools installed on each node (via puppet) to get tags or can I just get instance names via facter and then process them into tags before they will be used in puppetmaster ?

Comment: You dont need ec2 tools installed, you only need curl. You should learn how to write your own facts, really comes in handy `http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/custom_facts.html`

Comment: @PiotrJasiulewicz added description of custom fact creation.

Comment: Yes, found custom facts from my research, this all seams to be straight forward, but how do I go from having the instanceid in facter on the node, to having a tag name from the instance on pupeptmaster? If I have 20 instance id's still hard to classify on that.

Comment: Instance ID was used as an example of how to create a custom fact. Ammend the address curl uses to get something from user-data that you use to differential server type.

Comment: Yeah, but there really isnt that much to differentiate on in that api.

Comment: Good answer, but no longer appropriate as facter has EC2 facts built-in since 1.7 :)

Answer (score 3):

As of facter 1.7 (released in April 2013), there are built-in facts that report various details of your EC2 instance.

Reference: http://docs.puppetlabs.com/facter/1.7/core_facts.html#ec2ec2-instance-data

Comment: Tags seem to be missing from the available facts though. That's a shame as it seems none of the other facts are user-configurable. I guess we still can't use this as a makeshift ENC.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Sirch that at this point custom facts seem to be the way to go. AWS describe using Cloud formation facts at:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples/IntegratingAWSCloudFormationWithPuppet.pdf

Which is an interesting, if difficult read. The custom fact from it is:

```
# cfn.rb 
require 'rubygems' 
require 'json' 
filename = "/var/lib/cfn-init/data/metadata.json" 
if not File.exist?(filename) 
 return 
end 
parsed = JSON.load(File.new(filename)) 
parsed.default = Hash.new 
parsed[\"Puppet\"].each do |key, value| 
 actual_value = value 
 if value.is_a? Array 
  actual_value = value.join(',') 
 end 
 Facter.add(\"cfn_\" + key) do 
  setcode do 
   actual_value 
  end 
 end 
end
```

They then configure their nodes like:

```
node basenode { 
 include cfn 
} 
node /^.*internal$/ inherits basenode { 
 case $cfn_roles {
   ...cloud formation include...
 } 
}
```

I'm more inclined to implement this via hiera like:

```
---
:backends:
  - yaml
:yaml:
  :datadir: /etc/puppet/hiera
:hierarchy:
  - "roles/%{::cfn_roles}"
  - common
```

Then have something like common.yaml:

```
classes: cfn # or whatever your custom fact class is
```

roles/dbserver.yaml:

```
classes: mysql
```

roles/webserver.yaml:

```
classes: httpd
httpd::port: 8080
...
```

Jeff